# jQuery create multiple HTML elements without overwriting old HTML

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, sharepoint

I would like to make a dynamic jQuery function that counts the results from the array and than makes for every object in the array an HTML element.
The array is made by an SharePoint API.
So if there are 3 results/objects run the code 3 times. If there are 2 results/objects run the code 2 times.

With the code below it creates the last result(object) from the array and overwriting the previous made ones.

I was thinking about a piece of code that counts the object and then use the append() function to add the HTML fields. loop it as many times as there are objects. But not sure this is the best way.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "http://URL/_api/web/webs",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
  success: function (data) {
           console.log(data.d.results);
           var aSites = data.d.results;
           jQuery(aSites).each(function(i,oSite){
               var sTitle = oSite.Title;
               var sURL = oSite.Url;
               console.log(sTitle, sURL);
               jQuery('.wrapper').html(jQuery('<div class="Title"><p>Title:</p><input type="text" name="fname" id="inputTitle"></div><div class="URL"><p>URL:</p><input type="text" name="fname" id="inputURL"></div>'));
               jQuery( "#inputTitle" ).val(sTitle);
               jQuery( "#inputURL" ).val(sURL);
           });
    },
  error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `.append()`, not `.html()`, so it adds to the DIV instead of replacing it.

Comment: Also, IDs have to be unique. You can't use `id="inputTitle"` and `id="inputURL"` on each one.

Comment: Append worked thanks :) I will put the object ID behind the ID in the div. Than it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.append()`, not `.html()`, so you add instead of replacing. And you can't use the same ID each time, use a class instead.

```
success: function (data) {
   console.log(data.d.results);
   var aSites = data.d.results;
   $('.wrapper').empty();
   jQuery(aSites).each(function(i,oSite){
       var sTitle = oSite.Title;
       var sURL = oSite.Url;
       console.log(sTitle, sURL);
       var newDIV = jQuery('<div class="Title"><p>Title:</p><input type="text" name="fname" class="inputTitle"></div><div class="URL"><p>URL:</p><input type="text" name="fname" class="inputURL"></div>'));
       newDIV.find(".inputTitle" ).val(sTitle);
       newDIV.find(".inputURL" ).val(sURL);
       $('.wrapper').append(newDIV);
   });
},
```